# How to create a Bottom Sheet with dynamic content in Android

Tags: android, material-design, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm currently creating an app based on the google maps api to locate specific places.
What I want to do is : when the user clicks on a marker, the Bottom Sheet displays specific informations about this marker, and if it's a new marker that the user wants to add, only a button is displayed.

What's the best way to do that? Should i change the textviews' content in the onMarkerClick() method of my activity or should I set a fragment in the Bottom Sheet?

Thank you

Comment: You should add new layout (contain textview, button.... ) in bottom mapview, and set visibility for this layout to Gone or Visible when click on map marker

Comment: but should I use a fragment to change the specific informations displayed in the bottom sheet for each marker or just change the text in the activity main thread ?

Comment: Go for bottomsheet dialog. Is will be good